# WCF RIA EntityQuery returns null for Foreign Keys

Tags: silverlight, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, prism, wcf-ria-services

I'm following a [tutorial](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Working-with-Prism-4-Part-3-Composite-Command-and-Pub-Sub-Events.aspx) on Silverlight and Prism, where **WCF RIA Services** are uses to access the **Northwind database** through an **ADO.NET Entity Data Model**.

In the Northwind database, there is a table Order_Details which is connected to two other tables (Orders and Products) via foreign keys:

[image: Picture of Data Model]

The code to query the database looks like this:

```
EntityQuery<Order_Detail> detailQuery = _MyDomainContext.GetOrder_DetailsQuery();

_MyDomainContext.Load(detailQuery.Where(
            det => det.Order.Customer.CustomerID == cust.CustomerID).OrderByDescending(
            det => det.Order.OrderDate).Take(10), OnDetailsLoaded, null);
```

and then in OnDetailsLoaded:

```
var details = loadOp.Entities;
if (details != null)
        {
            var detailsList = details.ToList();
            detailsList.ForEach(det => Orders.Add(
                new OrderItem
                {
                    ProductName = det.Product.ProductName,
                    Quantity = det.Quantity,
                    OrderDate = det.Order.OrderDate.Value
                }));
```

This gives me a Null Exception at `new OrderItem`, because both Product and Order are null. I have set my EntityDataModel to "Include Foreign Key Columns in the Model". The code is exactly as in the tutorial, I only had to recreate the ADO.Net EntityDataModel and the DomainService to work with my local database, so the error is probably somewhere there.

How would I debug this error? I have no previous experience with databases. I'm using SQL Server 2012 with a Northwind database adapted for 2012, while the tutorial was written with SQL Server 2008 RC.

Comment: you might be able to use Fiddler2 to see the http request and responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I had to do to solve the problem. Josh's answer was part of the solution, but I also had to add [Include] attributes to the metadata:

In MyDomainService.cs, add `.Include()`:

```
public IQueryable<Order_Detail> GetOrder_Details()
    {
        return this.ObjectContext.Order_Details.Include("Order").Include("Product");
    }
```

In MyDomainService.metadata.cs, add `[Include]`:

```
internal sealed class Order_DetailMetadata
    {

        // Metadata classes are not meant to be instantiated.
        private Order_DetailMetadata()
        {
        }


        [Include]
        public Order Order { get; set; }           

        [Include]
        public Product Product { get; set; }


    }
}
```

This is described in detail at [this website](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/WCF-RIA-Services-Part-5-Metadata-and-Shared-Classes.aspx), thanks to [Brian Noyes](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Working-with-Prism-4-Part-3-Composite-Command-and-Pub-Sub-Events.aspx) for pointing it out to me.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to include the Product / Order explicitly in the load method.  Try doing a

```
.Include("Order").Include("Product")
```

inside the domain context load.

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't make a difference. `public IQueryable<Order_Detail> GetOrder_Details()
        {
          return this.ObjectContext.Order_Details.Include("Order").Include("Product");
        }
`